# WPF Pass Grid to UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently working on a .NET Framework 4.7.1 WPF application. I'm new to WPF and I want to pass a button to a UserControl:

```
<!-- UserControl Start -->
<Grid Name="MyGridFrame">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

   <!-- Column1 Start-->
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
       <!-- Some content -->
    </ScrollViewer>
    <!-- Column1 End-->

    <!-- Column2 Start-->
      <!-- Here I would like to display my Button from outside -->
    <!-- Column2 End-->
</Grid>
```

I would then want to use my MyGridFrame component like this:

```
<local:MyGridFrame>
   <Button x:Name = "button" Content = "Click Me"/>  
</local:MyGridFrame>
```

I would like to use my UserControl to kind of "frame" my button component. Unfortunately I don't know how to do this.

Do you have any idea how I can pass my button component to the MyGridFrame component?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a template for your `UserControl`. Add a `<ContentPresenter />` element as the placeholder for the element to be inserted:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.MyGridFrame"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
            <Grid Name="MyGridFrame">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <!-- Column1 Start-->
                <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                    <!-- Some content -->
                </ScrollViewer>
                <!-- Column1 End-->

                <!-- Column2 Start-->
                <ContentPresenter />
                <!-- Column2 End-->
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

...and add the `Button` like this:

```
<local:MyGridFrame>
    <Button Content = "Click Me"/>
</local:MyGridFrame>
```